# PHP copy() max size problem

Tags: php, download, copy, php-ini

I transferred a download script onto my QNAP today from my publish server, which basically uses copy() to download a video from a URL. For some reason any video I download comes out at exactly 33,378,304 bytes. My php.ini file is set to 3600 timeout and it does not make a bit of difference, anyone else had this problem?

When I run the script directly using

```
# php <script path>
```

The php.ini is ignored and the full file is downloaded, there must be a line I'm missing in the config.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

upload_max_filesize is set to 2047M

Comment: What's your PHP memory limit set to? 32 Mb perhaps?

Comment: 33,378,304 bytes is  31mb - try to grep your php.ini and find 31 may be it will help you.

Comment: @hadvig there are no 31's in the file.

Comment: @sander-marechal The memory limit is set to 256M.

Comment: Is that what it says in php.ini or what it says when you replace the `copy` call with a `phpinfo()`? Scripts can change theit memory limit. It's possible that it is 256M in your php.ini but that a script sets it to 32M dynamically.

Comment: @sander-marechal It's 256M even in the phpinfo() call - take a look http://goo.gl/jYyFw

Comment: What is your [`default_socket_timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout)?

Comment: @wrikken It's set to 3600 values are view-able from this link http://goo.gl/jYyFw

Comment: @Lewis: hm, if it works for the command line go the easy route: do a `var_export(ini_get_all());` from both the command line & the webserver, and `array_diff` those 2. At least you can then quickly see what's different.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around rather than a solution to the problem but have you tried using `exec("cp $src $dst")` or `system("cp $src $dst")`

as far as I can see there is no limit for the `copy()` command in PHP which makes this a strange bug.

Comment: I'm using copy to download from a URL, afaik cp doesn't do the same job.

Comment: you could use `wget` in place. `system("wget -O $dst $url")`. Do you have access to the http server that's serving the file? Can you see any errors reported there regarding the transfer?

Comment: wget doesn't work for this URL for some reason. And I'm unable to view the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Have you changed the `post_max_size` value too?

-

**EDIT**

Some video servers protect themselves by forbidding the download of more than a specific portion of the video (I already the same issue while trying to download video streams).

As a workaround, you can use this script to download the video piece by piece:

```
function fragmented_download($url, $destination)
{
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    $downloadsize = $headers["Content-Length"];
    for ($filesize = 0 ; $filesize < $downloadsize ; $filesize = filesize($destination))
    {
        exec("wget --continue --output-document='$destination' '$url'");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's set to 'post_max_size = 2047 M'

Comment: OK. You didn't mention it in the question, and it often is be a source of trouble.

Comment: That's okay, I've been staring at this php.ini file for hours now with no luck.